# string and char variable was not declared in this scope C++

Tags: c++

I want to create  a program which is able to count the characters in a word.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// ask the user to input the word, at least contain 5 characters
    do
    {
    string inputWord = "";
    cout << "please enter your word to be counted = \n";
    cin >> inputWord;
    }while(inputWord.size() < 5);

// ask the user to input a character
    do
    {
        char searchCh = '0';
        cout << "please enter a character from \n" << inputWord;
        cin >> searchCh;
    }while(searchCh.size()<1 && searchCH.size()>1);

// iterate over the word
    for(int i=0;i < (int) inputWord.size(); i++)
    {

    // get the character
        char ch = word.at(i);
    // if the character matches the character we're looking for
        if(searcCh==ch)
        // increment counter
        {
            counter++; // counter = counter + 1
        }
    }

// output the number of times character appears
    cout << "the word " << word << " contain character " << searchCh << "is" << counter;

    return 0;
}
```

and I always get the error: `inputWord was not declared.`
What is the cause this error?

Comment: `(searchCh.size()<1 && searchCH.size()>1)` - `searchCh` is a `char`, it stores exactly one character, and you can't call member functions on it.

Comment: inputWord is declared in the scope of the do{...}while() loop. Outside of the loop you don't have access to the variable. If you need to, declare the variable before the loop starts. Same for searchCh ....

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: Read the compiler message completly. It is not about "not declared" it is about "not declared here". Find the place where it is declared. Find the scope it is declared in. See that it ends before the line in question.

Comment: `string inputWord = "";` has block scope so declare it outside of the  do while loop and you will no longer get that error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about scopes. Variables in c++ have visibility and lifetime in scope, in which the were declared. For instance, inputWord is visible and exists only in the first do-while loop. Move its declaration above loop. Your code has many such errors. Moreover, I do not see, where is counter declared and it should be properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the `inputWord` as string, please check your compiler works for that or not because some compilers do not take the specifier "string". Also `searchCh`, `counter` and `word` is also missing from your program. First of all declare these variables properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up a lot of variable names and used variables outside their scope. 
Here is a working version of your code with a few debugs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// ask the user to input the word, at least contain 5 characters
string inputWord = "";
char searchCh = '0';
char ch;
int counter=0;
    do
    {

    cout << "please enter your word to be counted = \n";
    cin >> inputWord;
    }while(inputWord.size() < 5);

// ask the user to input a character

        cout << "please enter a character from \n" << inputWord;
        cin >> searchCh;

// iterate over the word
    for(int i=0;i < (int) inputWord.size(); i++)
    {

    // get the character
         ch = inputWord[i];
    // if the character matches the character we're looking for
        if(searchCh==ch)
        // increment counter
            counter++; // counter = counter + 1
    }

// output the number of times character appears
    cout << "the word " << inputWord << " contain character  " << searchCh << " is " << counter;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define the "inputWord" before start the while loop , like this :

```
string inputWord = "";
```

do
    {

```
cout << "please enter your word to be counted = \n";
cin >> inputWord;
}while(inputWord.size() < 5);
```

because "inputWord" is inside  the loop ,